# Using a docker image as a dependency, I want to run multiple commands in docker compose but can't do it

Tags: docker

I want to create a generalized docker-compose yaml that can take any parent image/docker file build it if it doesn't exist and then run the following commands to run it in flask.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command: >
      RUN pip3 install flask
      && COPY ./app /app
      && WORKDIR /app
      && RUN python run.py
```

But I keep getting an error

```
starting container process caused "exec: \"RUN\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Not sure why.

Anyways, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say create a generalised `dockerfile` instead of compose.

Because when you use `command`, it runs your command on your container and RUN, COPY etc are not linux commands, these are dockerfile instructions.

Though you can run `pip install && python run` in `command`, bur copy is not possible from host to container usinh `command`.

Use below instructions in `dockerfile`

`RUN pip install flask`

`COPY ./app /app`

`WORKDIR /app`

`CMD python run.py`

And in `docker-compose.yml` you can overwrite the `CMD` defined in `dockerfile`
With something like this:

`command:`

`python some.py or parameters`